# Any way to test for 404 errors at different domains from Google Chrome extension code?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

My wife has over 12k Pinterest pins and there are many that resolve to 404 errors. I thought it would be simple to just create a chrome extension she could run that would get the pins, then I would test the URLs for 404 errors and then perform a delete.

Creating the plugin wasn't difficult but of all things, I am getting hung up on being able to determine whether the remote URL is a 404 due to CORS issues. Using fetch with a mode of no-cors does not error but it doesn't return me anything that I can use to determine whether the link is valid or not. I understand the purpose of CORS, but I'm just surprised that there isn't a way to tell from javascript whether or not a domain is valid.

I've seen some approaches where it was stated to use a proxy which I guess you append the headers with, however I thought I would see if there was any creative means of telling whether an endpoint is even existent or not. I'm really only interested in capturing the broken links so I can then go about deleting the pins programmatically. I was going to go about testing whether I could use an iframe to assign src to the url and see if I'm able to extract any more info that way, but figured I would post here to see if there are any other creative approaches. I also tried performing a fetch for favicon.ico, thinking it would get around CORS due to it being an image and not the full page, but this didn't work as well as I was hoping.

If you have any ideas, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Would using `curl` or Postman not be easier? Contrary to browsers, those tools are not subject to the Same-Origin Policy...

Comment: This actually might be a great idea as long as I can run from JS. Essentially once I get the list of bad links, I am then going to navigate programmatically to delete the bad pins. I will be looking into making calls tonight to curl from js and will eventually provide my results here as to whether it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: Why the JS requirement? Could you not issue the request to delete the bad pins from `curl` and Postman?

Comment: No dont have access to their pinterest dev API....I requested access but i still have yet to hear back so just doing this through document queries and interactions via javascript.